# How to draw multiple shapes in android drawable one after the other similar to vertical oriented Liner layout

Tags: android, drawable, shapes, geometry, layer-list

I want to draw following shapes - Line and Circle one after the other using android drawable.Please see the attached screen-shot.

[image]

Comment: you cannot do that, use `Canvas` API instead

Comment: can we not draw two shapes in drawable @pskink?

Comment: where do you want to use it?

Comment: I want to show the tracking of any placed order using this drawable.

Comment: tracking of courier or delivery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146535/discussion-between-akash-bisariya-and-pskink).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have find solution shown below.
The gap between circle and line is achived using a hack. I just draw a stroke over the circle with white color so that it will look like a gap between the circle and line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:width="150dp"
    android:height="10dp"
    android:gravity="center">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="90">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/c_green_text" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
<item
    android:width="20dp"
    android:height="20dp"
    android:gravity="center">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="@color/c_white" />
        <solid android:color="@color/c_green_text" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: how can I start with circle and then the line?

Comment: and the current code is drawing circle over the line not under the line.

Comment: In layer list you can put one drawable over another @Andrain

Comment: Requires API > 23!

Answer (score 0):

You can check below link, this might help you.

https://github.com/ernestoyaquello/vertical-stepper-form

Comment: I just want to draw Line and Circle without any animation.What is the need of library for it?